# angular ng-map doesn't centers correctly

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps

i have tried this code

```
<ng-map id="ng_Map" center="{&map.center&}" zoom="8" zoom-to-include-markers="auto" min-zoom="8"  max-zoom="13" street-view-control="false" map-type-control="false"  style="height: 498px;">
```

but the map opens with different center when i open my web page but when i change location it opens correctly

also i have tried this also

**google.maps.event.trigger(angular.element("#ng_Map"), 'resize');**

but nothing happens

also i used $setTimeout and also all the plugins are included

Comment: What is center="{&map.center&}" evaluated to ? center should be an array   of 2 points

Comment: yes it is an array of two points i have made a function which runs on init and also when i change the position but init function doesnot provide center although variable map.center has value in it(lat,lng)

Comment: Can you show us the value of `center`?

Comment: Object   center: Array(2)    0: 43.467517    1: -79.6876659     length: 2 
   __proto__: Array(0)     marker: Array(1)    __proto__: Object